# Guess_number script adding WHILE into guess_number and run it

Tags: linux, bash

```
num=$(($RANDOM%11))
input=10
while [$num=input];do
    read -p "Enter an Integer between 0 and 10:" input
    echo "correct"
    if [ $num -ne input ];then
        echo "incorrect guess"    
    fi
```

keep getting syntax error unexpected end?

Answer (score 1):

You have some significant `logic` and `syntax` errors in you code in addition to the missing `done`. First your `test` clauses will both **fail** due to `syntax` errors. The `[` test construct requires a `space` between the `[` and `]` and the test clause inside. Your tests also contain `syntax` errors regarding missing `$` before the variable names and an incorrect `=` in the first. They should both be written:

```
[ $num -ne $input ]
```

Your logic would better include the `echo "correct"` as an `else` to the `if` clause to prevent `correct` from being output with every number. A version without these issues would look like:

```
#!/bin/bash

num=$(($RANDOM%11))
input=10

while [ $num -ne $input ];do

    read -p "Enter an Integer between 0 and 10: " input

    if [ $num -ne $input ];then
        echo "  incorrect guess"
    else
        echo "  correct!"
    fi

done

exit 0
```